# GetCharWidth32 and Point Size issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fonts, gdi+

Currently I have the following function to attempt to get the character widths for specific characters in a string. It returns the same values for a font regardless of point size. I know this is in logical units. What multiplier do I need to take into account to get it out of logical units and into pixels?

Thanks!

```
double Utils::GetFormattedCharWidth(char theChar, Gdiplus::Font* pFont, RectF&     rectArc, Graphics& graphics)
{
   double textWidth = 0;

   HDC hdc = NULL;
   DWORD outLine = 0; //= GetLastError();
   hdc = graphics.GetHDC();  
   outLine = GetLastError();
   LPINT lpBuffer = new int;
   /*ABC *abc = new ABC[256];
   for(int iCon = 0; iCon < 256; iCon++)
   {
      (&abc[iCon])->abcA = 0;
     (&abc[iCon])->abcB = 0;
     (&abc[iCon])->abcC = 0;
   }*/
   DWORD dSize = 0; 
   SetMapMode(hdc,MM_TEXT);       
   HGDIOBJ hOldFont = SelectObject(hdc, pFont);
   outLine = GetLastError();
   //outLine = GetLastError();
   //DWORD d = GetGlyphOutline(hdc, theChar, GGO_METRICS, lpg, dSize, lpvBuffer, LPM);
   DWORD d = GetCharWidth32(hdc, theChar, theChar, lpBuffer);
   //lpABC = (LPABC)GlobalAllocPtr( GHND, 256*sizeof(ABC) );
   //d = GetCharABCWidthsA(hdc, 0, 255, abc);
   outLine = GetLastError();
   //DWORD d = GetCharABCWidthsA(hdc, theChar, theChar, abc);
   int iExtraSpacing = GetTextCharacterExtra(hdc);
   outLine = GetLastError();
   graphics.ReleaseHDC(hdc);
   textWidth = (double)(*lpBuffer) ;
   //delete abc;
   delete lpBuffer;

   graphics.ReleaseHDC(hdc);

   return textWidth + iExtraSpacing;
}
```

New code for Mark using Measure String.

```
double Utils::GetFormattedCharWidth(char theChar, Gdiplus::Font* pFont, RectF& rectArc, Graphics& graphics)
{
   double textWidth = 0;

   char charBuff[4];
   memset(&charBuff, 0, 4);
   charBuff[0] = theChar;
   RectF rectTemp;
   WCHAR* pChar = (WCHAR*)charBuff;

   graphics.MeasureString(pChar, 1, pFont, rectArc, &rectTemp);
   textWidth = rectTemp.Width;

   return textWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select a GDI+ Font into a GDI DC. I'm pretty sure that's not going to work. You need a GDI handle to the font.

Comment: Interesting. What type of handle would I need? Where can I get it from in GDI?

Comment: Or even better what function would I want to use for GDI+?

Comment: @Alikar, try Graphics::MeasureString or Graphics::MeasureDriverString.

Comment: Unfortunatly that gets the character cell I believe and not the character glyph. See edit for new code. I've tried this before and the characters end up very wide because this call does not take into account the width of the glyph itself and not the kerning of the characters its next to. Also it still gives back the measurements in logical character units instead of pixels.

Comment: Stupid 5 minute limit. Anyway I think it may give it back in pixels. I think just have an error in my code. Still giving the cell though unfortunately.

Comment: @Alikar, as long as you haven't given a non-default mapping, logical units and pixels should be the same. Also it looks like GetCharABCWidths is what you want, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183418(v=VS.85).aspx. You'll need to call Font::GetLogFont[A/W] to get the characteristics of the font, then CreateFontIndirect to make a copy of the font.

Comment: I've looked into that one and I get a System Error Code 8 after I call the function and a zero return for it, which according to the documentation means that it fails. I think windows is trying to get at the Open font instead of the TT Font for Arial resulting in the function being confused as to which to get. I've tried GetCharWidth32 and that seems to work, but the character widths returned are very small. Such as 4 or 8 pixels for a 25 point font. Either function seems to fail continually. Perhaps its because I'm using a GDIPlus font? Strange that it would take it in without errors then.